# Adding extra elements in a combined array

Tags: php, arrays

I have had help in creating a combined array that takes in elements from associated arrays, the arrays have urls and scores which are taken from search engines, when the urls match the score is added together in the combined array, here is the code

```
$combined = array(); 

foreach($bingArray as $key=>$value){ // for each bing item
if(isset($combined[$key]))
    $combined[$key] += $value['score']; // add the score if already exists in $combined
else
    $combined[$key] = $value['score']; // set initial score if new
}
```

the same code is then ran for $googleArray, this works just fine but now I want to add the values that have been commented out in the code below

```
foreach($jsonObj->d->results as $value)
    {   $i = 0;
        $bingArray[str_replace ($find, '', ($value->{'Url'}))] = array(         
        //'title'=> $value->{'Title'},
        //'snippet' => $value->{'Description'},
        'score' => $score--
     );
```

I'm sure its simple to alter the the first foreach loop to do this but I'm not sure how to,can any help please

Comment: Could you give the example of outcomes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to define each of your array elements as an associative array containing a score, title and snippet element.

```
$combined = array(); 

foreach($bingArray as $key=>$value){ // for each bing item
if(isset($combined[$key]))
    $combined[$key]["score"] += $value['score']; // add the score if already exists in $combined
else
    $combined[$key] = array("score"=>$value['score'],"title"=>$value["title"], "snippet"=>$value["snippet"]); // set initial score if new
}
```

To access the score you will just

```
echo $combined[$key]["score"];
```

Comment: I seem to be getting a syntax error at the last line of the code

Comment: he forget to add `)`before semicolon.

Comment: opps ... I had a = instead of => on the snippet assignment as well. Updated code.